# Disable Xcode 8 code completion for image name

Tags: ios, xcode8

Is there any way to disable code completion hints for image name in Xcode 8?

[image]

Comment: now that's a feature right there

Comment: Is this the case for both images in the bundle and images in an xcasset?

Answer (score 4):

According to the manual you can't select what the code completion shows and not, since the code completion shows all the assets that it has to the apps disposal in its surrounding context. If xcode thinks it should first provide you with images from the asset catalogue, it will unfortunately do so.

You can turn the code completion of in the text editing preferences or you can toggle the code completion on and off when typing with Control-Space bar and you can dismiss the code completion with the Escape key. If you turned the code completion off in the text editing preferences you can still turn them on with Control-Space bar.

Answer (score 1):

I created a snippet with the completion shortcut "in" that replaces itself with "in" to stop it from suggesting images when I'm trying to write a Swift closure. If you have other annoying use cases perhaps further snippets might help.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a temporary solution by installing this plugin.

https://github.com/keith/IgnoreXcodeImageCompletions